# Cannot find the class file for com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseDocumentInternal?

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases

I have problem, when i compile maven project in Ubunt*, im getting error message, 
but when I compile the project in windo## im not get error,

the error message is ..

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot
>   find the class file for
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseDocumentInternal. Fix
>   the build path then try building this project

My pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0rc9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-object</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0m2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0rc9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-enterprise</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Help me guys.
im sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Check the versions in your pom.xml, you have a mix of 1.0rc9, 2.0.5 and 3.0.0m2.

Please set everything to 3.0.0m2 (beta, not suitable for production) or 2.2.27 (latest stable)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0m2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0m2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-distributed</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0m2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-lucene</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0m2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-gremlin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0m2</version>
    </dependency>
```

(btw, I really can't figure out how it can work on Win...)

Comment: 2.2.27 or 2.2.0

Comment: You should always work with latest stable (see http://orientdb.com/download/), 2.2.27 contains a lot of bug fixes compared to 2.2.0

Comment: Thanks,

Can I Upgrade OrientDb without remove the existing Database?

Comment: It depends on what version you created it with. If you created it with a 2.0 or 2.1 and you are upgrading to 2.2, we always suggest to export/import http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Export-and-Import.html